# UIImageView displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using the Custom Picker by ray, when I press a button a picker is pop-ups then when image is chosen it will dismiss the picker and displayed the image in UIImageView. I put in the `viewWillAppear` but when I go to another `ViewController` the image chosen disappears. How to maintain the chosen in UIImageView to be displayed even after going to different View Controllers, only will it change if another image is chosen again.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    secondView.image = _imagePicker.selectedImage;
}

- (IBAction)chooseCustomImageTapped:(id)sender {
    _imagePicker = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init];
    _imagePicker.title = @"Choose Custom Image";
   for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
    { 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]]; 

        if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:savedImagePath]){ 
            [_imagePicker addImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath]]; 

        } 
    } 
     [self presentModalViewController:_imagePicker animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should take your image in `UIImage` object just after selection done `UIImage *image =  _imagePicker.selectedImage;`, and retain it till next change. Then set that image to your image view `secondView.image = image;`.

Comment: is there any delegate that is been called after you select iamge frrom this delegate?

Comment: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate - this

Comment: can you show me the code that u are using after image is selected, actually as per my knowledge when your `imagePicker.selectedImage` set to NULL after your view appear next time..

Comment: that's all the code sir, the rest is the sample class of ray wenderlich `custom image picker`

Comment: Okay dear, so when you go to another `UIViewController` (call `view2`) how you return back to your previous `view`(call `view1`)? By `dismissModelViewController` or you reallocate you `view1` in `view2` class.

Comment: I'm using storyboard so modal view controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12794/discussion-between-rptwsthi-and-dexter)

Answer (score 0):

Did you alloc a new view controller when you go to the specified view controller? If so, when you go to a new view controller, you alloc it, so all the datas has been initalized.

Answer (score 0):

use the pickerview delegate function.

```
    - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
         // put your logic here.

 NSUserDefaults *udf=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [udf setObject:@"Imagename" forKey:@"LastSelectImage"];

    }
```

accordingly your image has change your image name here.

Comment: set your .h file uimagepickerdelegate.

Comment: this isn't what I'm asking for.

Comment: in that didselectrow of pickerview you use nsuserdefalut for last image name put it. while you return in the view. get that image from nsuserdefault

Comment: I don't get this `[udf setObject:@"Imagename" forKey:@"LastSelectImage"];` part. Haven't tackle NSUserdefaults yet

Comment: oh just did that last your select image. and change your viewwill appear section NSUserDefaults *udf=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; secondView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[udf objectForKey:@"LastSelectImage"]];

Comment: as per your selection image name or path of the image.

Comment: how ever you save the image in your application. so that saved image name is pass here.